# Can't compile linux kernel with -Og/-O0 option for debugging purpoces

Tags: linux-kernel, debugging, gdb, optimization

Having custom hardware running embedded Linux (OpenWrt) like a charm. CPU - is IMX6ULL (ArmV7) so it is supported by Jlink to debug over JTAG interface.
Starting GDB server and step by step debugging Linux kernel shows lot of `optimized out` messages because of kernel compiled with `KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -O2 -fno-reorder-blocks -fno-tree-ch $(EXTRA_OPTIMIZATION)` flag.
So I am trying to compile it with `-O0` that provides me following option:

```
$ make -j64 V=s all
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  ....
  AR      built-in.o
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
  WARNING: modpost: Found 4 section mismatch(es).
  To see full details build your kernel with:
  'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
  arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi-ld: arch/arm/kernel/setup.o: in function `setup_arch':
/opt/eclipse/imx6ull-openwrt/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a7+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/linux-imx6ull_cortexa7/linux-4.14.199/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c:1134: undefined reference to `psci_smp_ops'
  arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi-ld: /opt/eclipse/imx6ull-openwrt/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a7+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/linux-imx6ull_cortexa7/linux-4.14.199/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c:1134: undefined reference to `psci_smp_ops'
  arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi-ld: kernel/panic.o: in function `__xchg':
/opt/eclipse/imx6ull-openwrt/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a7+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/linux-imx6ull_cortexa7/linux-4.14.199/./arch/arm/include/asm/cmpxchg.h:110: undefined reference to `__bad_xchg'
  arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi-ld: kernel/exit.o: in function `__xchg':
```

Checked for `WARNING: modpost: Found x section mismatch(es).` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40288/warning-modpost-found-10-section-mismatches). Seems that resulted binary file takes more space then configured by some settings. The `vmlinux` size built with `-O2` option is `39Mb`. Using `-O1` gives me `37Mb` image so I hope there is enough space in my DDR3 RAM (128Mb) to feet for even bigger image compiled with `-O0` configuration. So I am wondering about way to provide more space for sections? Could someone please point me to place I can do it? Have limited knowledge about Linux kernel so was unable to find any linker script used for that.